# How did Angel Eyes become a sergeant in The Good, the Bad and the Ugly?

Tags: plot-explanation, character, the-good-the-bad-and-the-ugly

When Blondie and Tuco are captured as Confederacy soldiers, Angel Eyes is a Sergeant in the Union army.

Is there any explanation for this or is it just assumed that he stole the papers and the uniform from a dead Union sergeant?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can find in the [IMDb FAQ](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0060196/faq) an answer to the question

> Was Angel Eyes really a Union officer when Blondie and Tuco are captured?

The answer

> No. He was only disguised as one to get closer to the gold. It's possible he murdered the real Union officer and stole his identity. In the film novelization by Joe Millard, after the battle of Glorietta Pass, he finds the body of "Sergeant Allen Crane", assigned "to adjutant duty at [Battleville] Prison Camp", and steals the man's orders and uniform.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, I appreciate it very much.